# sensing and representation matrices from exhaustive data

Tags: image-processing, matlab

If I know **y** (samples) and **x** (signal), is there a practical matlab algorithm to calculate **A** in **y = Ax**?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is probably not unique.

$$    \left[ { \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} } \right] \left[{\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}} \right] =    \left[{\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}} \right] $$

$b$ and $d$ can be any value provided $a = c = 1$

Comment: @jonsca thank you very much for the math formatting !

Comment: You're welcome.  The matrix syntax is a little cumbersome, but it makes a nice result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tensor factorization methods. For example if you are sure that your data is non-negative, then Nonnegative Matrix Factorization might be used.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nnmf.html

Depending on your application and format of A, you might want the sparsest solution. In that case minimization of $L_0$ norms would be considerable.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. The data is an image so they are all nonnegative values. I'm working with matrix completion algorithms but I first wanted to test an incoherence property - see http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/13567/4038